# twitter bootstrap mvc3 collapse

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

i having a wired issue with TB and MVC3 in this fidel [working exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/miko5054/YWUmb/119/) it use TB v2.0.2

but in my mvc3 project im using TB v2.1.1 and the collapse dont work...

this is all the scripts reference

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>MainSearch</title>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/DataTables/media/css/DT_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/boostrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DataTable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jQuery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DataTable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-collapse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DT_bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
```

thanks

miki

Comment: I believe that bootstrap.js includes bootstrap-collapse. Try removing the direct include of bootstrap collapse.

Comment: have looked at the problem through a web inspector ? does the console show any errors ?

Comment: @ThatSteveGuy its includes in the main boostrap.js ,
i removed the  bootstrap-collapse.js but no result

Comment: @keshav no error in the console  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by changing the JS/CSS **order**

i guess the best practice should be JQUERY  should be first than  the Main bootstrap Js than the other bootstrap Js extension

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-collapse.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/datepicker/css/datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/boostrap/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTable.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTable.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```